# Typescript: Object of type 'unknown'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch, generator, redux-saga

I have a **generator** function `foo()` in which I am calling an **API** using `fetch`.
After I receive the **response** from the **API**, I am parsing it as **JSON**.

Typescript is throwing an error: `Object of type 'unknown'` in this line -> `const msg = yield response.json();`

```
function* foo(val: ValType): Generator {
    const response = yield fetch(endPoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(val),
    });

    if (response) {
        // typescript throws error
        // that type is unknown for
        // the response object
        const msg = yield response.json();
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: The consumer of `foo` can `yield` anything they wish. Did you mean to use `await` instead of `yield`, and `async` instead of `*`?

Comment: What @CertainPerformance said: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgGwCrmgXigbwL4CgDGA9gHYDOwUExAJgAqECWxFGARKwNy65ykjH4oAMwCuA4AxIAqYYUIAKAG6IAXLEQpIASky4o+qETIUAThFJgSpdFDgB3OAwpCIwfAAt5VOo2YAaLD0DYIBbV3dCajUAcloAeQBlJGi-IOD9ACNIkDUAKQS4gDkAOnITJgBzBiEQJUQtVODsLS40qGqoeTMLKwgtQPSDAHohqFBIUnxysApgdxNCO1JKEwWTNuCRsfc4WdR25bEAa2JF4ll1wf0tuehuyzJoQgyAKwh8YA2DI3IoENIKlAMCAGBAENQoPdesUXqQSPIWl99GZgCITOd-hUuE1cHggA

Comment: You should use **async** and  **await** just to make sure that you are fetching data before you test if you got any result

Comment: @CertainPerformance I didn't mean to use `await` as I am using `foo` for Redux Saga.
I am not sure if `async/await` can be used in Redux Saga as only generator functions can be used.

Comment: @besartm I can't use `async/await` as I'm working with **Redux Saga**

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you didn't declare of type for `response`. Use must declare types for Generator function like this.

```
function* foo(arg): Generator<YieldType, ReturnType, ArgType> {
  // 
}
```

No need of declaring yield type, return type and argument type separately, Typescript can infer them if you declare it this way.

[Read more](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-6.html#stricter-generators)